# Wrap text around image in cell using iText 7

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, itext7

I have a PDF document with a table. The code is the following:

```
PdfWriter _writer = new PdfWriter(@"C:\output.pdf");
PdfDocument _document = new PdfDocument(_writer);
Document MyDocument = new Document(_document, PageSize.A4);

Table MyTable = new Table(new float[] { 1, 4 });
MyTable.SetWidthPercent(100);
MyTable.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("ID")));
MyTable.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("Description")));

MyTable.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("1")));
Cell descCell = new Cell();
descCell.Add(IMG); // iText.Layout.Element.Image
descCell.Add(new Paragraph("This is the description."));
MyTable.AddCell(descCell);

MyDocument.Add(MyTable);
MyDocument.Close();
```

*Actually the output is this:*

[image]

*What I am trying to achieve is this:*

[image]

I have read several examples for iText 5 and all point to using this property:

> image.setAlignment(Image.LEFT | Image.TEXTWRAP);

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be avaliable on iText 7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Floating images are not currently supported in iText7, but that's on the roadmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating elements functionality has been implemented in `7.0.3-SNAPSHOT` and is likely to make it into `7.0.3` release.

In order for the text to wrap around an image in a cell, you would need to specify that an image is a floating element, just like in HTML. To do that, use

```
Image img = ...
img.setProperty(Property.FLOAT, FloatPropertyValue.LEFT);
```

Then, construct a cell as usual by adding an image and text to it:

```
table.addCell(new Cell().add(img).add(textStr);
```

The output would look like the following:

[image]